# Selenium Explicit Wait fails to wait for clickability

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am having an issue with selenium explicit wait for a button to be clickable. When the button webelement is returned by

```
self.driver_wait.until(
            expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'login-btn'))
            )
```

I am getting an obstruction error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <a id="login-btn" class="fm-btn fm-btn-ghost-white account"> is not clickable at point (886,96) because another element <div id="ot-pc-content" class="ot-pc-scrollbar"> obscures it
```

Ironically it explicitely states, that the element is not clickable, although the explicit wait instruction should wait exactly for this to my undestanding ...

I tried to wait until the obstructing element is not visible anymore, but that didn't help:

```
    self.driver_wait.until(
        expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element((By.ID, 'ot-pc-content'))
        )
    button_login_1 = self.driver_wait.until(
        expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'login-btn'))
        )
```

I guess this behaviour will be reproducible using this minimum example, that includes everything needed from a class definition:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
import time
import datetime as dt
from typing import Union

class Session_FLM:
    def __init__(self,
                 url: str = 'https://www.freelancermap.de/',
                 browser: str = "FireFox",
                 session_time: Union[None, dt.datetime] = None,
                 use_fixed_wait_default: bool = False,
                 default_wait_time_fixed: float = 1,
                 default_explicit_wait_max: float = 10,
                 implicit_wait_max: float = 10
                 ):
        self.browser: str = browser
        if session_time:
            self.session_time = session_time
        else:
            self.session_time = dt.datetime.now()
        self.url: str = url
        self.cookies: bool = False
        self.default_explicit_wait_max: float = default_explicit_wait_max
        self.use_fixed_wait_default: bool = use_fixed_wait_default
        self.default_wait_time_fixed: float = default_wait_time_fixed
        self.implicit_wait_max: float = implicit_wait_max
        self.driver: Union[
            webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver,
            webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver,
            None] = None    
        self.driver_wait: Union[WebDriverWait, None] = None     
        self.headers: dict = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
            }
     
    def init_webdriver(
            self,
            url: Union[str, None] = None,
            use_fixed_wait: Union[bool, None] = None,
            wait_time_fixed: Union[float, None] = None,
            activate_implicit_wait: bool = False,
            implicit_wait_max: Union[float, None] = None,
            explicit_wait_max: Union[float, None] = None
            ) -> None:

        if not url:
            url = self.url
        if not use_fixed_wait:
            use_fixed_wait = self.use_fixed_wait_default
        if not wait_time_fixed:
            wait_time_fixed = self.default_wait_time_fixed
        if not implicit_wait_max:
            implicit_wait_max = self.implicit_wait_max
        if not explicit_wait_max:
            explicit_wait_max = self.default_explicit_wait_max

        if self.browser == 'Chrome':
            driver_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            driver_options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'        # wait for entire page content to be loaded
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=driver_options)
        elif self.browser == 'FireFox':
            driver_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
            driver_options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'        # wait for entire page content to be loaded
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=driver_options)

        self.driver_wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, explicit_wait_max)

        if activate_implicit_wait:
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(implicit_wait_max)
        self.driver.get(url=url)
        if use_fixed_wait:
            time.sleep(wait_time_fixed)

    def cookies_handling(
            self,
            accept_cookies: bool = False,
            use_fixed_wait: Union[bool, None]  = None,
            wait_time_fixed: Union[float, None] = None
            ) -> None:
        """
        Handle freelancermap cookies.

        Args:
            accept_cookies (bool, optional): True: Accept all cookies; False: Enter cookie details and only accept obigatory cookies.
            use_fixed_wait: (Union[bool, None], optional): Only use fixed wait if True
            wait_time_fixed (Union[float, None], optional): Fixed waiting time, which is used whenever "Selenium Implicit Wait" is set to be inactive; overrides "Session_FLM" objects default fixed waiting time.
        """     

        if not use_fixed_wait:
            use_fixed_wait = self.use_fixed_wait_default
        if not wait_time_fixed:
            wait_time_fixed = self.default_wait_time_fixed

        if accept_cookies:
            button_accept_cookies = self.driver_wait.until(
                expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler'))
            )
            button_accept_cookies.click()
        else:
            button_settings_cookies = self.driver_wait.until(
                expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'onetrust-pc-btn-handler'))
                )
            button_settings_cookies.click()
            if use_fixed_wait:
                time.sleep(wait_time_fixed)
            button_accept_selected_cookies = self.driver_wait.until(
                expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'save-preference-btn-handler'))
                )
            button_accept_selected_cookies.click()

        if use_fixed_wait:
            time.sleep(wait_time_fixed)

    def login(
            self,
            email: str,
            password: str,
            use_fixed_wait: Union[bool, None]  = None,
            wait_time_fixed: Union[float, None] = None
            ) -> None:
        """
        Login with an existing freelancermap account.

        Args:
            email (str): Account email
            password (str): Account password
            use_fixed_wait: (Union[bool, None], optional): Only use fixed wait if True
            wait_time_fixed(Union[float, None], optional): Fixed waiting time, which is used whenever "Selenium Implicit Wait" is set to be inactive; overrides "Session_FLM" objects default fixed waiting time.
        """          

        if not wait_time_fixed:
            wait_time_fixed = self.default_wait_time_fixed
            
        if use_fixed_wait:
            time.sleep(wait_time_fixed)
        self.driver_wait.until(
            expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element((By.ID, 'ot-pc-content'))
            )
        button_login_1 = self.driver_wait.until(
            expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'login-btn'))
            )
        button_login_1.click()
        if use_fixed_wait:
            time.sleep(wait_time_fixed)
        input_field_email = self.driver.find_element(
            By.ID,
            "login"
        )
        input_field_email.send_keys(email)
        input_field_pw = self.driver.find_element(
            By.ID,
            "password"
        )
        input_field_pw.send_keys(password)
        button_login_2 = self.driver_wait.until(
            expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.fm-btn-primary:nth-child(1)'))
            )
        button_login_2.submit()
        self.driver_wait.until(
            expected_conditions.url_to_be('https://www.freelancermap.de/mein_account.html')
            )
        if use_fixed_wait:
            time.sleep(wait_time_fixed)
        self.driver.back()
        if use_fixed_wait:
            time.sleep(wait_time_fixed)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    flm = Session_FLM(
        url='https://www.freelancermap.de/projektboerse.html',
        default_wait_time_fixed=2
        )
    flm.init_webdriver(activate_implicit_wait=False)
    flm.cookies_handling(
        accept_cookies=False,
        use_fixed_wait=False)
    flm.login(
        email='abc',
        password='123', 
        use_fixed_wait=False
        )
```

- Clicking the button works, when `cookies_handling()` is called with the argument `use_fixed_wait=True`.
- Clicking the button works, when `login()` is called with the argument `use_fixed_wait=True`.
- Clicking the button works, when `cookies_handling()` is called with the argument `accept_cookies=False`, as in this case the obstructing element won't appear at all.
- Clicking the button fails, when all those parameters are set to `False`.

I would really love to understand what is the problem with my approach and how to cope with it without adding `time.sleep()`.

Comment: The exception is telling you that the element can't be clicked because another element is covering it. The element *would be* clickable if it wasn't covered. This is to preserve the user scenario where a user tries to click the element but another element  (the covering element) receives the click.

Comment: Also, that is not minimum code ([mcve]). 90% of that code is not required to repro this issue. We also can't run your code because it's behind a login. The blocking element HTML is provided in the exception message. Find that element on the page and figure out how to dismiss it (if it's dismissable) or find a different locator for the same element that isn't obscured. When all else fails, you can fall back to using JS to click the element.

Comment: @ JeffC: Thanks for looking into this. 
The code is not behind a login. Actually the non-clickable button is the button to open up the login interface.
The minimum example is a reduced version of a self-made class, that includes all the steps to come to the erroneous point. As I don't understand the reason for the error I decided to keep it foor providing all info that might be useful to find the rootcause. You can cop/paste it and it will produce the error. 
Unfortunately my approach to wait for the obstructing element to disappear also failed, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: When a click() method is run, Selenium will first scroll the element into view, then click the center point of the element, but first it checks to see if the center point click will be gobbled up by another element which is overlaying it.  Even if it is clickable (which basically means it exists, it's style is set to visible and is enabled), it can throw this error... (or an element not interactable error if it's outside of the viewport)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should have posted as an MCVE,

```
url = 'https://www.freelancermap.de/projektboerse.html'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "login-btn"))).click()
```

The rest of your code is irrelevant to the error and just creates confusion and obfuscates the issue.

This code works just fine on my machine. From looking at the HTML provided by the click intercepted exception, it looks like the cookie banner is what your code is clicking. My suggestion is to accept or otherwise dismiss the cookie banner first, then proceed with the rest of your code and you shouldn't have any issues.